# Rails + Devise: How to override redirect for the before_filter "authenticate_user!"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am on Rails 3 and the latest version of Devise, and I have a before filter in my `AdminController` to `authenticate_user!` I need to store a session variable for the `request.referrer` before it redirects so that I can send it back to the /admin page when they try to go on it. Where would I overwrite `authenticate_user!`?

What I want to do is this, but I don't know where to define it:

```
def authenticate_user!
  session[:return_to] = request.request_uri
  super
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need to do that, devise will respect an `after_sign_in_path` for this exact purpose.

In your application controller:

```
before_filter :set_return_path 

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource) 
  session["user_return_to"] || root_url 
end

def set_return_path
  unless devise_controller? || request.xhr? || !request.get?
    session["user_return_to"] = request.url
  end
end
```

From the devise helper:

```
# The default url to be used after signing in. This is used by all Devise
# controllers and you can overwrite it in your ApplicationController to
# provide a custom hook for a custom resource.
# def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
```

Comment: nice thanks! I also thought of another solution, which is to change the before filter to a custom method `before_filter :custom_authen` and then do a `def custom_authen; session[:return_to] = "/admin"; authenticate_user!; end;`

Comment: @Edmund Well you can do it that way, make sure you also include the `after_sign_in_path_for` method as described to consume the session variable you write to. The benefit of the method in my answer is it doesn't only redirect to a static path, it will redirect to wherever the user was trying to go.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Matt's answer, which doesn't require the return page to be recorded upon every page view:

In application_controller.rb:

```
# Only remembers the page immediately before we 
# redirect them for auth, instead of every page view

def authenticate_user!
  session["user_return_to"] = request.fullpath
  super
end

# Deletes the return path as soon as it's used, so 
# they aren't accidentally redirected back again
# next time they login

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session.delete("user_return_to") || root_path
end
```