# Devise issue in my Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

this method is not working in my application and doesn't give any error, i am using devise and have watched the Devise episode RailsCast , i wrote this as I watched but nothing happend , what can do ??? I have searched but cannot find it
what is the necessary steps to do ?

```
<% if user_signed_in? %><%= current_user.email %><% end %>
```

I am using RubyMine , `user_signed_in` and `current_user` marked as Cannot find .

From `Rails Console --sandbox`

```
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 3.2.12)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
irb(main):001:0> user_signed_in?
NoMethodError: undefined method `user_signed_in?' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try with <%= current_user.email unless current_user.blank?%>

Comment: have you logged in to the application?

Comment: yes , I am using RubyMine , user_signed_in and current_user marked as Cannot find .

Comment: It seems that you have not logged into the application. You are trying as not loggedin user. Once you will logged in, then you can have current_user = the user object through which you have logged in. Now the current_user is returning nil.

Comment: question updated check it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in railscasts `root path` default is `root to: 'articles#index'`

means it access the `articles controller`
if you do the same as in this cast, you shoud add filter to the `articles_controller`
or to your own controller if you named it different:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

at the top of the controller

https://github.com/railscasts/209-devise-revised/blob/master/blog-after/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb

Comment: Can i add this filter to my Application Controller only to make it work at my whole app  ??

Comment: yes, but it will request authentication for all actions and that means you can't even access sign in probably, try it :)

Comment: yes that what I mean , instead of open every controller and add `before_filter :authenticate_user!` , can you give me a link for the other filters which can be used ?

Comment: have a look in here https://github.com/railscasts/209-devise-revised/blob/master/blog-after/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb almost all tricks available

Comment: so sorry, wrong link, here is the one  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers

Comment: thanks for help , i need a method to > if not authorized redirect to root path , how to add this ?

Comment: where exactly you need this? what actions from your controller you want to block for users? also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716679/rails-devise-how-to-override-redirect-for-the-before-filter-authenticate-use

Answer (score 2):

Try this

In your controller write

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```